# jQuery Pin It Impementation

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make the navigation bar on this site:

contemporarypool.biz "sticky" using jquery.pin. However, I'm new to the javascript world, and am not having success with implementing this script. I have the javascript called in the header, I'm not sure how to call the navigation bar.

To pin an element you're suppose to use this: $(".pinned").pin()

Does the class go where .pin is? Where do I include this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">            
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
       jQuery(".nav-content").pin(); 
    });                
</script>
```

Where ".nav-content” would be the class that you apply the pin to.

You can put it anywhere after your jQuery file that is included.